# Reach parameters in trigger function postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a trigger before insert to check if parameters match requirements. I tried many things and if I hardcode values for the d and e it works as expected and raise an error in case if e!=d. But when I replace it with variables from NEW it doesn't work. Table with a trigger has columns id and languagetag_id.
Could you please tell me what I do wrong?

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION insert_name() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_name$
declare d int;
declare e int;
    begin  
        d = (select distinct languagetagid from "scheme".table1 as a
                                    left join "scheme".table2 as b on (a.id = b.country_id )
                                    where b.id = NEW.id);
        e = NEW.languagetag_id;                     
    IF ( e != d ) THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'error: % ', e;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
$insert_name$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER insert_name BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON "scheme".table
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_name();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql TRIGGER shows incorrect NEW value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087093/postgresql-trigger-shows-incorrect-new-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `NEW` and `OLD` values, the trigger must be executed for every row, not for the entire statement

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_name BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON "scheme".table
     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_name();
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect an error in trigger, only in function.
It works now.